# Are there any limits where it is easier to integrate using L'Hopital's Rule?

Tags: limits

Generally, we use the principles behind L-Hopital's Rule to say that
$$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$
Yet this implies that
$$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x \to a}\frac{\int f(x) dx}{\int g(x) dx}$$
Are there any scenarios where it is simpler to use this property than to use the traditional form of L'Hoptial's Rule?

Comment: Your example is incorrect, as to use L'H rule the fraction needs to be 0/0 or $\infty/\infty$ in the limit.

Comment: @vadim123 Wow, I can't believe I missed that. Thank you. That was really stupid of me.